# C# override/add methods/fields to an object

Tags: c#, .net, ruby, inheritance, subclass

I have a library that creates and setups objects for me, then I can use those objects to do stuff.

Let's say I'm given object "a" of class "A"

So I want to override a method in that *specific* object, I don't want to change the code of its class because that would require changing the library.

In Ruby I can do that using Singleton Classes, like:

```
class FirstClass
    def test
        p "test"
    end
end

o = FirstClass.new

class << o
    def test
        p "overridden"
    end
    def extraMethod
        p "ok"
    end
end

o.test # prints "overridden"
o.extraMethod
```

Now how can I do the same in C#?

**Update**

I ended up not using the answer I submitted because it's too ugly and it requires changing all private fields in the base class to either protect or public to make them exist in the derived class hence I can copy values from base to derived.

The way I ended up using is to pass a Type derived from the base class to the library and change the library so that it creates instances using:

```
(A)Activator.CreateInstance(mytype, arguments);
```

Comment: What do you want that for? It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

C# doesn't (directly) support runtime extension of types, other than via the `dynamic` mechanisms.

The closest option would likely be to use `ExpandoObject` with `dynamic`:

```
dynamic o = new ExpandoObject();
o.a = 10;

o.ExtraMethod = new Action( () => Console.WriteLine("ok") );

// Invoke
o.ExtraMethod();
```

That being said, this is not a typical way to work with C#.

Answer (score 1):

To "override a method" in runtime (notice the quotes) is possible in C# by using [Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass()
    {
        //set the default
        OverridableMethod = () => MessageBox.Show("Default!");
    }

    public void StandardMethod()
    {
        //Call it.
        OverridableMethod();
    }

    public Action OverridableMethod {get;set;}
}
```

usage:

```
var some1 = new SomeClass();
some1.StandardMethod(); //Shows "Default!"  
some1.OverridableMethod(); //Shows "Default!"

var some2 = new SomeClass {OverridableMethod = () => MessageBox.Show("Override!!")};
some2.StandardMethod(); //Shows "Override!"  
some2.OverridableMethod(); //Shows "Override!"
```

Comment: @SpaceMonkey If you needed this kind of extensibility you should have accounted for it when writing your initial code. There's no way around it now.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ugly way to do this actually.

I was thinking of using inheritance and downcasting, but downcasting is invalid.
However, you can use reflection to achieve the same outcome.

```
static void Main()
        {
            A a = new A();
            a.FieldA = 999; // change the object
            a.test(); // "This is A and FieldA is 999"

            //B b = (B)a; // => Error: Invalid you cannot downcast !

            // using reflection we turn "a" into an instance of B that is a copy of the old "a"
            a = new B(a);
            a.test(); // This will call the method in B: "Calling the new method"  "This is B and FieldA is 999 and FieldB is 10"

            // a.newMethod(); => Error cannot access this method because "a" is declared as an instance of A (even though it's actually of B now)

            B b = (B)a; // Now downcasting works fine (because A is an instance of B actually)

            b.newMethod(); // works as expected: "This is B and FieldA is 999 and FieldB is 10"
        }



        class A
        {
            public int FieldA;

            public A()
            {
                FieldA = 100;
            }

            virtual public void test()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is A and FieldA is {0}", FieldA);
            }
        }

        class B : A
        {
            int FieldB;
            public B(A a)
            {
                // copy all fields
                foreach (FieldInfo pi in typeof(A).GetFields())
                    GetType().GetField(pi.Name).SetValue
                       (this, pi.GetValue(a));

                // add this field:
                FieldB = 10;
            }

            // We can override methods
            override public void test()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Calling the new method:");
                newMethod();
            }

            // Add a new method but it will only be visible after casting A to B
            public void newMethod()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is B, FieldA is {0} and FieldB is {1}", FieldA, FieldB);
            }
        }
```

So I have overridden the methods within "a" and added new fields to it.

I realise this doesn't achieve the same as what you can do in Ruby, but at least I can override methods and add methods/fields that can be used inside the methods I'm overriding.

Comment: Very ugly and useless (I think) way of doing things. If the base class doesn't have the virtual method to be overriden, the only way is to use extension methods. If you CAN modify the base class, put directly those methods as virtual with an empty implementation.

Comment: @MikeSW extension methods cannot override.

Comment: Extension methods are the only way to ADD behavior when you CAN'T override methods.

Comment: @MikeSW I agree that it's ugly though

Comment: @MikeSW But that's just it, extension methods aren't adding behavior to that class.  It's an entirely separate method that only syntactically *appears* to belong to that class, even though it doesn't.  It's very different from actually mutating the class's public API at runtime as the OP's example does in Ruby, or that is sometimes done in JavaScript.

Comment: I didn't say it actually modifies the base class definition but extension methods are the way in .net add BEHAVIOR to a base class you can't modify(override) or inherit. C# is not Ruby and it's not a dynamic language.  You can at most generate new methods at runtime using Light Code Generation and attach the dynamic method to an existing type but you must have a very good reason to do so as it's not trivial.