# Restricting Access to a Method or Rewriting that Method for a Specific Object

Tags: c#, .net, methods, overriding, visibility

(In a C# program) I have a `List<Author> authors`, where `Author` is a class I wrote. `Lists` have a default `Add(Object o)` method, but I need to make it either less accessible or overwrite it for specifically my `authors` object.

So far, I've found information on polymorphism, extension methods (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632392/extension-method-for-listt-addtofrontt-object-how-to)), and [delegates in combination with dynamic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592868/c-sharp-override-add-methods-fields-to-an-object), but I'm not sure if what I'm asking is possible in the first place without keeping things simple and creating a new class that inherits from `List<Author>` (I figure that even *that* doesn't make sense, given that I would only use the class once).

Note that unlike [this scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629981/is-there-a-way-to-restrict-access-to-a-public-method-to-only-a-specific-class-in), I don't have access to the `List<T>` class, so I can't make the method virtual or partial, or create an overflow that hides the original method.

Given the situation, how would I make the existing `Add(Object o)` method private and overwrite it with a public method? Is the best solution the separate class, or something more complicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to roll your own class in this instance with the new Add method

```
class MyCustomList<T> : List<T>
{
    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        //your custom Add code here
        // .... now add it..
        base.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Instantiate it with something like this:

```
MyCustomList<Author> sam = new MyCustomList<Author>;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose that works. I was hoping there was something that didn't require creating a new class, but I'll use this for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to encapsulate the List in its own class. The best option is to write your own collection, backed by a list. Then you can add your custom logic to the add method.

Example:

```
public class AuthorCollection : IList<Author>
{
    private IList<Author> backingAuthorList;

    public AuthorCollection(IList<Author> backingAuthorList)
    {
        if (backingAuthorList == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("backingAuthorList");
        }

        this.backingAuthorList = backingAuthorList;
    }

    public void Add(Author item)
    {
        // Add your own logic here

        backingAuthorList.Add(item);
    }
}
```